# string parsing optimization : ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I am working on a parser that is currently way too slow for my needs (like 40x slower than I would like) and would like advice on methods to increase my speed.  I have tried and am currently using a [custom regex parser](https://gist.github.com/1511123), aswell as a custom parser using [strscanner class](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/StringScanner.html).  Ive heard a lot of positive comments on [treetop](http://www.rubyinside.com/treetop-powerful-but-easy-ruby-parser-library-701.html), and have considered trying to combine the regex into one huge regex that would cover all matches, but would like to get some feedback w/ experience before I rewrite my parser yet again.

The basic rules of the strings that I am parsing are:

- 3 segments (BoL operators, message, EoL operators)
- ~6 BoL operators
  BoL operators can be in any order
- 2 EoL operators EoL operators can be in any order
- Quantity of any specific operator can be 0, 1, or >1 but only 1 is used rest are removed and discarded
- Operators in the 'message' section of the string are not captured / removed
- Whitespaces is allowed before & after operators but not required
- Some BoL operators can have whitespace in the setting

My current Regex parser works by running the string through a loop that checks for BoL or EoL operators 1 at a time and cutting them out, ending the loop when there are no more operators of the given type as so...

```
loop{ 
if input =~ /^\s+/ then input.gsub!(/^\s+/,'') end
if input =~ /reges for operator_a/ #sets 
   sets operator_a
   input.gsub!(/regex for operator_a)/, '')
elsif input =~ /regex for operator_b/ 
   sets operator_b
   input.gsub!(/regex for operator_b/,'')
elsif input =~ /regex for operator_c/
   sets operator_c
   etc .. etc .. etc..
else
break
end
}
```

The question I have, What would be the best way to optimize this code?  Treetop, another library/gem that I have not found yet, combining the loops into one huge regex, something else?

Please restrict all answers and input to the Ruby language, I know that it is not the 'best' tool for this job, it is the language that I use.

More specific grammer / examples if that helps.
This is for parsing communication commands sent to a game by users, so far the only commands are say, and whisper. The begenning of line operators accepted are ::{target}, :{adverb}, ={verb}, and #{direction of}.  The end of line operators are {emoticon (aka. :D :( :)}, which sets adverb if not already set, and end of line puncutation which sets verb if not already set.
the character ' is an alias for say, and sayto is an alias for say::
examples :

> ':happy::my sword=as# my helm Bol command operators work.

```
{:action=>:say, :adverb=>"happily", :verb=>"ask", :direction=>"my helm", :message=>"Bol command operators work."}
```

> say yep say works

```
{:action=>:say, :message=>" yep say works"}
```

> sayto my sword yep sayto works as do EoL operators!:)

```
{:action=>:say, :target=>"my sword", :adverb=>"happily", :verb=>"say", :message=>"yep sayto works as do EoL operators!"}
```

> whisper::my friend       :     happy Bol command operators work with
>   whisper.

```
{:action=>:whisper, :target=>"my friend", :adverb=>"happily", :message=>"Bol command operators work with whisper."}
```

> whisp:happy::tinkerbell and they work in a different order.

```
{:action=>:whisper, :adverb=>"happily", :target=>"tinkerbell", :message=>"and they work in a different order."}
```

> ':bash=exclaim::hammer BoL operators work in this order too.

```
{:action=>:say, :adverb=>"bashfully", :verb=>"exclaim", :target=>"hammer", :message=>"BoL operators work in this order too."}
```

> sayto bells =say :sad #wontwork Bol > Eol and directed !work with
>   directional? :)

```
{:action=>:say, :verb=>"say", :adverb=>"sadly", :direction=>"wontwork", :message=>"Bol > Eol and directed !work with directional?"}
```

> 'all EoL removed closest to end used and reinserted. !!??!?....... :)
>   ? :(

```
{:action=>:say, :adverb=>"sadly", :verb=>"ask", :message=>"all EoL removed closest to end used and reinserted?"}
```

Comment: A small improvement might be had by extracting the regexps into variables before the loop: `op_a_re = /regex for operator_a/; loop { ... input ~= op_a_re ... }`; this way you call implicit `Regexp.new` once, instead of once per loop iteration. Although, my admittedly very very simple benchmark only sped up by 5% on 1.9.2..

Comment: @Amadan Very good point! I had thought of doing that when I got to the code 'clean-up' phase, but hadn't thought about it affecting speed aswell. TY

Comment: Without knowing much about what you're trying to parse, the question is difficult to answer. It sounds more like a real grammar would be beneficial, but that doesn't necessarily mean it would be *faster*. Without examples, it's tricky to theorize.

Comment: @JosephRuby The regex approach is wrong, and essentially impossible to maintain. Hurry and stop. The grammar is still unclear, but I think you're better off with a different approach.

Comment: @JosephRuby Yep, and the grammar is still unclear. Grammars are most easily understood when documented generically. No suggestions at this point, although it *looks* like some splitting and checking for command-ness might be enough, or switch to something like treetop. Can't tell if the grammar is regular-enough to benefit from TT though.

Comment: @JosephRuby Still looks like a more-naive split would work, but w/o spending more time on it, not sure. It might even be doable w/ an internal DSL if you make a few concessions, or possibly a thin layer over an internal DSL making a real grammar much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this syntax is useful in your case:

```
emoti_convert = { ":)" => "happily", ":(" => "sadly" }
re_emoti = Regexp.union(emoti_convert.keys)
str = "It does not work :(. Oh, it does :)!"

p str.gsub(re_emoti, emoti_convert)
#=> "It does not work sadly. Oh, it does happily!"
```

But if you are trying to define a grammar, this is not the way to go (agreeing with @Dave Newton's comments).

Comment: I honestly didn't know that a regex'ed hash could be used in a gsub like that very nice trick!  Don't think it will help in this case though.